# Django, Dajax and Javascript - onclick not calling python method

Tags: javascript, python, django, dajaxice, dajax

I've been at an issue after attempting to implement Dajax into my Django project.

At a certain point during the installation and usage instructions of the Dajax website, I was instructed to call a method in ajax.py as such:

```
<button type="button" onclick="Dajaxice.MyProject.MyApp.say_hello(Dajax_process)">Dajax</button>
```

But when I try to click said button, there is no response at all. It acts like a null button.

I'm still trying to figure out how Dajax would even recognize my say_hello function like this... but that's probably how Dajax is used.

I have my say_hello method implemented as follows:

```
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
from dajax.core import Dajax

@dajaxice_register
def say_hello(req):
    print "DAJAX"
    dajax = Dajax()
    dajax.alert("Hello World!")
    return dajax.json()
```

At first glance, I believed that it was problem with not finding the method at all. I'm still not 100 % sure if that is the reason. But it could be.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I should look for?

I have all the instructions on the page: http://django-dajax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-dajax

Thanks,
 David

Answer (score 1):

Currently leaped this hurdle myself.

Couple things to make sure of:

1. Download and install jquery, and put it somewhere you can call it. I put it in a static folder within my app: /my_site/example_app/static/js/jquery-2.0.3.js
2. You will need to load that in your HTML Head view using:

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>`
3. You will also need to make sure to call the dajax jquery core using:

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}dajax/jquery.dajax.core.js"></script>`
4. Next, before your run your server to test run

   manage.py collectstatic
5. This will copy everything django needs from Dajax/Dajaxice. I installed both of these into my normal Python2.7 lib, django pulls them from there and copies them to the needed folder.

This should get you going... I'm not expert here, but these steps helped to remedy my issue.

Also, if your copying code from Dajax's website, dont forget to change the app root in the onclick calls....

```
    <input type="button" value="callback!" onclick="Dajaxice.*EXAMPLE-APP-NAME*.saybye(my_js_callback);">
```

You'll need to change that from the above to "polls" or "example"... whatever the name of the app that runs that code is.